# Compute the VaR from NPV (Net present value)?

Tags: value-at-risk

A client is evaluating an investment in
Indochina requiring an initial expenditure (period 0) of 10,000, and
which then in periods 1 and 2 gives a benefit V1 and V2. Assume
that the discount rate to evaluate this project is r = 10%
(This rate is a known value and not a random variable). If the
benefits follow the following distribution:

[image]

What is the Value at Risk (VaR) of the NPV from such investment?

Comment: $NPV=V1/1.1+V2/1.1^2$ So NPV is normally distributed.

Comment: What about the VaR?

Comment: The VaR of a normal variable with known mean and variance is not too difficult to calculate.

Comment: Apologies, I am just introducing myself to working with multiple random variables

Comment: Yes but asking homework problems without showing attempts to solve is not a well-regarded approach to learning